# Can anybody recognize this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the following second-order equation?
$$f''(x)-bxf(x)-cf(x)=0,$$
where $b, c$ are constants.

Could anybody tell me its name and thus I can search the general solution to it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: the central term should be  "b x f '(x)", isn't it ?

Comment: @JeanMarie what I have is indeed two terms of $f(x)$, i.e., there is no term of $f'(x)$. Should this equation without $f'(x)$ be simpler?

Comment: @WeinEld: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%27%27%5Bx%5D+-+b+x+f%5Bx%5D+-+c+f%5Bx%5D+%3D+0

Comment: I don't say that. It just striked we that there are two $f$ and no $f ' $. Btw, why do you think that such an equation has a name ?

Comment: @Moo a doubly hairy solution...

Comment: @JeanMarie: Haha - agreed! :-)

Comment: @Moo Thank you for your help!

Comment: @JeanMarie Well, I am not sure it has a name, I just hoped to find more information for such an equation which occasionally is of interest to me.

Comment: $$f''(x)-bxf(x)-cf(x)=0 \text{ is an Airy ODE}$$
$$f''(x)-bxf'(x)-cf(x)=0 \text{ is an Hermite-Kummer ODE}$$

Comment: Following Jjacquelin, you're only going to find solutions by special functions or trying a series expansion. Fortunately for you Airy's is quite heavily understood!